# How to include JS file link into Browser console

Tags: javascript, browser, console, browser-console

I want to include a file into the Browser console.

I have used

```
document.write("<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-3.5.0.debug.js'></script>");
```

but i get this error:

> Refused to load the script
> '...' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
> 'nonce-74eCu_hm3_B6K5S7B4_qbQ' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample'
> 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:". Note that
> 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled.
> Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is
> used as a fallback.

Is their any way to paste a JS file link into the browser console?

Comment: `document.write()` has nothing to do with the console.

Comment: @Barmar OP probably tries to load some script onto the site from the dev tools

Comment: You could try `document.createElement('script')`, but I suspect you'll run into the same CSP error.

Comment: do you own the site you are trying to do this on? If so, update the content securty policy appropriately. If not, you're out of luck. If you don't know [what a content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) is, go read up on it.